# Existence of a bound for sign functions?

Tags: inequality

Is the following statement true?

$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}^d, ~ (\text{sgn}(a)^T\text{sgn}(b))^2\le (a^Tb)^2$

where $\text{sgn}(x) = \{1 ~\text{if} ~x \ge 0, -1 ~\text{if} ~x < 0 \}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider for example $a = b = 1/2$, then $$(\text{sgn}(a)^T\text{sgn}(b))^2 = 1 > 1/4 = a^Tb.$$
**EDIT:** More generally, this is wrong for any vectors $(a_1,\ldots,a_n),(b_1,\ldots,b_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $0\leq b_i,a_i \leq 1$ for every $i=1,\ldots, n$ and there exists $j$ with $a_j < 1$. Then for every $i$ we have $0 \leq a_ib_i \leq 1$,$\text{sgn}(a_i)\text{sgn}(b_i)=1 $ and $0 \leq a_jb_j < 1$, it follows that
$$(\text{sgn}(a)^T\text{sgn}(b))^2= \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \text{sgn}(a_k)\text{sgn}(b_k)\right)^2 = n^2 \\ > ((n-1) + a_jb_j)^2 \geq \left(a_jb_j+\sum_{k=1, k \neq j}^n a_kb_k\right)^2 =(a^Tb).$$